# How to extract sum of sales that have been reversed DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, extract

I need to manipulate the Sales measure to exclude any transactions which have been reversed.

Sales measure is as follows right now:

```
Sales ($) = 
IF (
HASONEVALUE ( 'Currency'[Detail] ),
SUMX (
    'Sales',
    'Sales'[Value_Sold]
        * CALCULATE ( VALUES ( 'Exchange Rates'[ExchangeRate] ) )
      )
)
```

**What steps and where would I add to extract Reversed Transactions from this measure? I tried below as that's what you'd do in EXCEL but that is not working - when pulling results, it can't display anything on the visual**

```
Sales - Reversals ($) = 
IF (
HASONEVALUE ( 'Currency'[Detail] ),
SUMX (
    'Sales',
    'Sales'[Value_Sold]
        * CALCULATE ( VALUES ( 'Exchange Rates'[ExchangeRate] ) ) - SUMX ('Sales', 'Sales [Trans_Type] = "Reversed")
          )
    )
  )
```

Comment: Is this really related to the <sql> _language_?

Comment: Why you just not exclude this 'Sales [Trans_Type] = "Reversed" ?? First argument of SUMX is a table that means you can put here this pseudocode (need optimization) -> CALCULATETABLE('Sales', NOT( 'Sales [Trans_Type] = "Reversed" ))

Comment: How would that look in terms of the full formula though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to exclude the reversed transactions from your first code, maybe this could help:

```
Sales ($) = 
IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( 'Currency'[Detail] ),
    CALCULATE(
        SUMX (
            'Sales',
            'Sales'[Value_Sold]
             * CALCULATE ( 
                VALUES ( 'Exchange Rates'[ExchangeRate] )
            )
        ),
        'Sales'[Trans_Type] <> "Reversed"
    )
)
```

It's basically adding the `SUMX` into a `CALCULATE` function which let's you make the some applied to filters (in this case not reversed transactions).

Comment: That is not letting me do this, it seems as though Sales [trans_Type] would have to be a measure rather than part of the table is that right?